# Error executin binary with JSCH

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to execute binary program (work with putty) on a Linux server, from java using jsch library:

```
Channel channel = null;
channel = session.openChannel("exec");
String command = "/users/let/Infot";
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command );
((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);

OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();
```

The error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libgrt1.so: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

In program like putty program works fine.

I am not allowed to change anything on the remote machine, and concatenating execution command with PATH doesn't help

```
command = "PATH=\"$PATH;/users/lib\" ; /users/let/Infot";


command = "PATH=\"$PATH;/users/lib\" && /users/let/Infot";
```

Comment: In my case I am not allowed to change anything on the remote machine, and concatenating execution  command with PATH doesn't help.

Comment: `PATH` won't help with shared libraries. For those, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: ok, now it's complaining on another LIB so it seems it's the right direction.

Comment: anyway now I failing on some "env" variables :(

Comment: Well, as mentioned in my answer, the problem is *on the server*. You should get it fixed. - Or use an **ugly hack** with `setPty`, also mentioned there.

Comment: What about adding this before command "ksh --login -c" can it be problematic?

Comment: Iam already using setPty , doesn't help. And there is no way to change anything on the server.

Comment: Yes, `ksh --login -c`, but that all depends if the login scripts won't do something that would break it too. But it' worth trying.

Comment: Yes it worked for me, binary works and recognizes all env variables, I just need to know if it can cause some issues.

Comment: There's no magical answer to that. It all depends on the scripts on the server. But as it works, I'd say it's ok.